# Net Project Build Problem

Tags: c#, .net, build

I have two Project , Project A and B  in one solution for example. Project A need refrence to Project B. 
when i change only Project A and Build Solution , I can't use exe with dll Project B .
Is there anyway to do so? With Assembly loader or something like that?

Comment: The question isn't clear. What do you mean by "I can't use exe with dll Project B"?

Comment: Can you explain what is exe with dll

Comment: @vahid Do you mean right click Project A in Solution Explorer "Add Reference" goto Projects tab select Project B?

Comment: How do you reference the .dll of Project B? What error messages are you getting? Did it work before recompiling Project A?

Answer (score 2):

If you have two projects and Project A is a reference to Project B. When you choose a reference you need to choose by project tab. The tab will show you all open projects of this solution

Answer (score 0):

[image]